# In Jenkins job config page, how to call a JavaScript function when my custom build step is added in the job config page?

Tags: javascript, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to create a Jenkins build step plugin.
In config.jelly, I want to do some initialization in JavaScript right after the build step is added in the page.

My config.jelly looks like this:

```
<f:entry title="IP" field="ip">
    <f:textbox name="ip"/>
</f:entry>
...

<script type="text/javascript">
    var ipInput = document.querySelector('input[name=ip]');
    // Do some intialization with ipInput.
</script>
```

However, it seems Jenkins parses the HTML and JavaScript content at different stages and ipInput always returns null in the JavaScript snippet above.

I could get around this issue by using setTimeout(), but that's not a reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this after the text input:

```
<st:once>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ipInput = document.querySelector('input[name=ip]');
        // Do some intialization with ipInput.
    </script>
</st:once>
```

If that doesn't work, another approach is to put the javascript in a separate file, e.g add the following to config.jelly:

```
<st:once>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${rootURL}/plugin/yourPlugin/js/yourPlugin.js" />
</st:once>
```

Then under src/main/webapp you would create a subdirectory js containing a file yourPlugin.js:

```
window.onload=function() {
    var ipInput = document.querySelector('input[name=ip]');
    // Do some intialization with ipInput.
}
```